# Adding item from another table in ms -access combo box

Tags: ms-access, events, combobox, ms-access-2010, subform

I have a combo box with row source = suplier.suplierid, suplier.supliername. I am using a search-as-you-type code:

```vb
Option compare database

Dim ssouce1 as string

Private sub Form load()
    Ssouce1 = Replace(Me.Suplier.rowsource, ";" ,"")
End sub

Private sub suplier_change()
    Call filtercomboasyoutype(me.suplier, source, "supliername")
End sub
```

And if the item is not in the list, I want to add a new supplier (not the written item) but to select one from a reserved list where I keep the possible suppliers.

I want that if the item is not in list, a new list appears so I can search again with search as you type and to add selected item in my combobox.

Comment: Why have a "reserved" list? Why not just one source for suppliers? Once selection is made from second source, it needs to be added to first source so it can be available to new data record? Why this duplication? Edit question to show current code for NotInList.

Comment: replicate your searchable combobox but base the new combobox on the reserved suppliers.   At the least, during the new combobox's afterUpdate event insert the new combo's selected supplier into the suppliers table and maybe remove it from the reserved suppliers.  I prefer using NotinList to throw an error suggesting adding a reserved supplier for which I add a button and a whole form.  However, you can run a macro from NotinList  to reveal the new Combobox or open that whole form.